# Magento 2 Migration problem

Tags: magento2, migration, base-url

I recently migrated my Magento store to a new server. I moved the whole store, import the database, the SSL certificates and modify domain dns so it points to new Server's IP.
The problem is that when I access to `domain.org` it shows errors in report, and those error files are being generated in the old server.
My base URL are using domain, not IP, so I don't what is causing this problem.
Do I need to change somewhere else the IP in Magento?

How is it even possible that when I type `domain.org` it access to the old server if the domain is pointing and replicating to the new server IP?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have solved the problem. In case you experience the same I did the following steps:

1. Delete the old dns zone
2. Clean cache from the old server
3. Run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
4. Run php bin/magento cache:flush
5. give permissions 777 to the store.

This did the trick and I could access to my website with the new server.

Comment: your commands are absolutely useless, DNS TTL cache probably was too long. also 777 permissions is very bad.

Comment: Well then post the right answer instead of insulting, this is an IT community, not just tell people that they are totally wrong without explaining.

Comment: please read my comment again, you will see it is self explanatory. also you stated in your answer as solved, so i pointed to some issues. if you think that little comments insulting you, then im not going to post any answers either. thank you